# View Inside a Stack view doesn't shown properly in iOS (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, uistackview

I tried to make a horizontal stack view that contains a view. below is my code, it doesn't work properly. also the corner radius not applied to the view

`````
        tag_stack.spacing = 30
        tag_stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tag_stack.axis = .horizontal
        stack_scroll.addSubview(tag_stack)
        
        for views in selected{
           
            let holder_view = UILabel()
            let container = UIView()
            
            container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            holder_view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            
            container.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
            container.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 47/255, green: 175/255, blue: 249/255, alpha: 1.0)
            container.layer.cornerRadius = 12.5
            
            container.addSubview(holder_view)
           
            holder_view.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
            holder_view.textColor = .white
            holder_view.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            holder_view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leadingAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
            holder_view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.trailingAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
            holder_view.text = views

            tag_stack.addArrangedSubview(container)
        }
        tag_stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stack_scroll.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        tag_stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stack_scroll.trailingAnchor).isActive = true````
`````

Comment: I understand that the corner radius is not applying. Override this function "viewDidLayoutSubviews()" and try to set container.layer.cornerRadius there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to add the required properties just go to properties and go to view attribute and check clipsToBound if you bound the control or you can fix this by added a line of code just add the

```
if (view.clipsToBound == true){
 view.clipsToBound = false 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to set the required properties. Do not forget to add `view.clipsToBounds = false` and `view.layer.cornerRadius = x` for the desired views.